# How to save/ upload file with OPA

Tags: file, upload, save, opa

How can I upload a file in opa server ? Is it possible to store the file in an opa database, or must I copy it onto the filesystem ?

The stdlib.io modules doesn't seem to offer the ability to store file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the Upload widget:
http://doc.opalang.org/api/#upload.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.upload

With the `process` callback you can decide to store the file in the opa database.